# Syntax Error in Visual Studio - Any comand

Tags: python, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, everytime i try to run a code, from the Terminal it sends a message like this one:

> 32/python.exe c:/Users/aaron/Desktop/Curso/test.py
>      ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>   `>>>`

I write 3+3 and it does the same thing.

Is it maybe a configuration error? Thanks